# Collapse button in Bootstrap 4 w/ PHP will open and show content but not collapse

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I recently attempted to use a collapse button to display content from a php query. The collapse button will show the content enclosed, but not collapse once it is opened. I troubleshooted many different possibilities that could be causing this issue, and only one gave me progress, which was putting the bootstrap JS CDN before the JQuery one. This made the collapse button work and it looked great, but it also broke a lot of my code and I got a console error warning me that Bootstrap's CDN should be after JQuery. For the record, I also attempted to move the if statement contained in the Div outside of it and use a variable instead, and it made no difference.

Here is a snipped of my code (Note that $comments is an array from php):

```
    echo "<head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>

        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk' crossorigin='anonymous'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
        <title>MelodyMate</title>
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
        <script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#replies'>View Replies</button>
                    <div id='replies' class='collapse'>";
                    if (isset($comments)){
                        $numofcomments = count($comments);
                        $commentnum = 0;
                        while ($commentnum != $numofcomments){
                            echo $comments[$commentnum];
                            $commentnum = $commentnum+1;
                        }
                    }
        echo "
    </div>
</body>";
```

Comment: What is inside the div? Plain text or html? Best way to troubleshoot is to put simple fake text, without the loop in php etc, and make sure the collapse is opening/closing. Then change the contents of the div.

Comment: Nawed, Inside the div there is currently html echo'd from php, but i changed out the contents with simple fake text, before posting "text", as i mentioned in the description. Still the same issue.

Comment: I am almost certain it is something to do with JQuery or Bootstrap, as when i switched the position of jquery and bootstrap in the head of my html it worked, but broke the rest of my code

Comment: @lincolnwilson well `bootstrap.js` depends on `jquery.js`, and you always load the dependencies first, so there should be no debate about which library to load first - you must load jquery first

Comment: zgood, I know this now and is why I changed it back, but still I have this issue.